# Python, sympy calculating multivariable function

Tags: python, sympy

Let us assume that we have two lists:

```
variables = ['a','b','c'...]
values = [1,2,3...]
```

and a simple product function:

```
function = 'a*b*c*...*z'
```

I tried to do this way (I do realize it is 100% incorrect, but I have no idea how to substitute multiple variables into a [sympified expression](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?sympy.core.sympify)):

```
import sympy
y = sympy.sympify(function).evalf(subs={variable:values})
```

Comment: Anyone miss `reduce()`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis `reduce` can definitely be very useful, but it's not needed here.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a complete example. You just need `zip` to mix the two lists. From the [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution) :

> To perform multiple substitutions at once, pass a list of (old, new)
>   pairs to subs.

```
from sympy import sympify

variables = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
values = range(1, len(variables) + 1)
expression = '*'.join(variables)
sub_table = zip(variables, values)
print values
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print expression
# a*b*c*d*e*f*g
print sub_table
# [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5), ('f', 6), ('g', 7)]
print sympify(expression).subs(sub_table)
# 5040
```

As a bonus :

- you don't need to build an extra dict
- you get an exact integer as output from `subs()`, and not just a float from `evalf()`.